# In yii2 how to give alias to columns

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-model

I was looking way to give alias to column names in select, I have tried following

```
Model::find()->select(['columnName' => 'columnAlias'])
```

but this give error unknown columnName, if I swap them, no data is being displayed in results array, however it give correct no of rows

Comment: `select(['columnAlias' => 'columnName'])` is correct syntax. If you are not getting data there is some other problem involved.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work.

```
Model::find()->select(['columnName as columnAlias']);
```

Also, here **columnName** should be replaced with the column you are trying to fetch, it's just for the info in case don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
Model::find()->select('columnName as columnAlias');
```

or

```
Model::find()->select(['columnAlias' => 'columnName'])
```